# Modal bootstrap for devise in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have created a modal for editing the profile through ajax. I have made a ajax call(remote true) for  "Edit profile" in devise. My edit.js file is like:

```
$('<%= j render 'edit' %>').modal()
```

I have a made _edit partial as:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit profile</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: {method: :put}, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= bootstrap_devise_error_messages! %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'email', class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: 'new-password', class: 'form-control' %>

        <small class="form-text text-muted"><%= t('.leave_blank_if_you_don_t_want_to_change_it') %></small>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: 'new-password', class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :current_password %>
        <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: 'current-password', class: 'form-control' %>
        <small class="form-text text-muted"><%= t('.we_need_your_current_password_to_confirm_your_changes') %></small>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit 'update', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer ">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I edit with failing validations i'm not getting the error messages. How to do this ? Do i have to add Update.js I tried that too but didn't get. Any suggestions are most welcomed

Comment: Can you use a debugger and see if the resource has any errors ?  As per your form, it is going to `create` action, you need to `resource.save`, if it fails, then check `resource.errors`.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna It is showing up errors.

Comment: Can you try doing this in your view ? `<% bootstrap_devise_error_messages!.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= key %> <%= value %></div>
<% end %>`. You can use [this](https://github.com/hisea/devise-bootstrap-views/blob/master/lib/devise_bootstrap_views_helper.rb) as reference.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna When i give without modal it worked with modal it's not working

Comment: Can you paste the server logs and also check if there is some error in browser console?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Have resolved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem guys. You have to add up **update.js** file where you write the js command to display the error in the edit modal. In update method of **registration controller** you have to add up a respond_to js if any error occurs. If any error occurs by default it will go to **edit.html**.